# Maximum sum of blocks of a Steiner Quadruple Systems of order 22

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S=\{0, 1, ..., 21\}$, and $T$ is a set of 4-subsets of $S$ (call these blocks), such that every 3 elements of $S$ appear in exactly one block of $T$.  This is known as a Steiner quadruple system.
$$m = \min_{t \in T} \{a+b+c+d \mid (a,b,c,d) =t \in T\}.$$
What is the maximum value for $m$?

I know $m \leq 24$.  So, I am trying to determine if $m$ can attain 24.